# Serialising BigInteger using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, biginteger, system.text.json, json-serialization, jsonconverter

I'm serialising a `BigInteger` to JSON using `System.Text.Json`:

```
JsonSerializer.Serialize(new {foo = new BigInteger(ulong.MaxValue) + 1})
```

This results in the following output:

```
{"foo":{"IsPowerOfTwo":true,"IsZero":false,"IsOne":false,"IsEven":true,"Sign":1}}
```

If I add a converter that casts the `BigInteger` value to a `ulong`, it of course fails because the `BigInteger` value is too big:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new BigIntegerConverter());
JsonSerializer.Serialize(new {foo = new BigInteger(ulong.MaxValue) + 1}, options);
```

This is the converter:

```
public class BigIntegerConverter : JsonConverter<BigInteger>
{
    public override BigInteger Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, BigInteger value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => writer.WriteNumberValue((ulong)value);
}
```

The output I want is:

```
{"foo":18446744073709551616}
```

I know this can be achieved with `JsonWriter.WriteRawValue` in Json.NET, but I am restricted to using `System.Text.Json`.

Is there any way to do this without manually hacking the serialised string?

Answer (score 6):

**In .NET 6** methods to write raw values directly have been added: [`Utf8JsonWriter.WriteRawValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonwriter.writerawvalue?view=net-6.0).  Thus `BigIntegerConverter` may now be written as follows:

```
public class BigIntegerConverter : JsonConverter<BigInteger>
{
    public override BigInteger Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.Number)
            throw new JsonException(string.Format("Found token {0} but expected token {1}", reader.TokenType, JsonTokenType.Number ));
        using var doc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader);
        return BigInteger.Parse(doc.RootElement.GetRawText(), NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, BigInteger value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        writer.WriteRawValue(value.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo), false);
}
```

Notes:

- The converter takes advantage of the fact that [`BigInteger.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.tostring?view=net-6.0#system-numerics-biginteger-tostring(system-iformatprovider)) returns a value formatted consistently with the JSON standard's formatting for numbers.
- There is no directly equivalent method `Utf8JsonReader.GetRawText()` that can be used during parsing. Instead you can parse to [`JsonDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument) and call [`RootElement.GetRawText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.getrawtext) to get the complete raw JSON token value as a string.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MsAr9Z).

**In .NET 5 and earlier**, writing a converter for `BigInteger` is a little awkward because, as you note, [`Utf8JsonReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader?view=net-5.0) and [`Utf8JsonWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonwriter?view=net-5.0) do not provide the ability to read and write raw JSON.  Instead, an intermediate `JsonDocument` can be used for both reading and writing an arbitrary JSON value like so:

```
public class BigIntegerConverter : JsonConverter<BigInteger>
{
    public override BigInteger Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.Number)
            throw new JsonException(string.Format("Found token {0} but expected token {1}", reader.TokenType, JsonTokenType.Number ));
        using var doc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader);
        return BigInteger.Parse(doc.RootElement.GetRawText(), NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, BigInteger value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var s = value.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
        using var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(s);
        doc.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QckmQj).