# C# JsonSerializer.Serialize<List<BigInteger>>(numbers) will output a json with a list of 0's

Tags: c#, biginteger, system.text.json

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Numerics;

List<BigInteger> numbers = new List<BigInteger>();
numbers.Add(4);
numbers.Add(3);
File.WriteAllText("example.json", JsonSerializer.Serialize<List<BigInteger>>(numbers);
numbers = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<BigInteger>>(File.ReadAllText("example.json"));
foreach(BigInteger i in numbers)
{
      Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

> output: 0 0

> expected: 4 3

It seems like Jsonserializer isn't serializing a list of BigInteger correctly.
what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is `knownPrimes` comes from?

Comment: Please post an [mcve].

Comment: was a mistake... fixed.

Comment: This already got closed as "Needs Debugging Details" for some reason, but in reality it looks to be a duplicate of [Serialising BigInteger using System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64788895/3744182).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean **knownPrimes** insted of **numbers** ?

```
var knownPrimes= JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<BigInteger>>

(File.ReadAllText("example.json"));
```

**Update** You can use this for working reference or testing

```
List<BigInteger> numbers = new List<BigInteger>();
            numbers.Add(4);
            numbers.Add(3);
            File.WriteAllText("example.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(numbers));
            var number = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BigInteger>>(File.ReadAllText("example.json"));
            foreach (BigInteger i in numbers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
```

Comment: no I mean numbers instead of knownprimes.

Comment: I updated my answer I use JsonConvert.SerializeObject and JsonConvert.DeserializeObject instead, Please mark it as answer if it helps.