# How do I write a float like "82.0" with the ".0" intact, using Utf8JsonWriter?

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

I've been struggling to write a double such as `82.0` using Utf8JsonWriter.

By default, the method `WriteNumberValue` method takes a double and formats it for me, and the format (which is the standard 'G' format) omits the ".0" suffix. I can't find a way to control that.

By design it seems that I can't just write a raw string to Utf8JsonWriter, but I found a workaround: to create a JsonElement and call JsonElement.WriteTo`. This [calls](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/b673eea8acacb1cdcfd5e59b7bbcab036eafa3ce/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Document/JsonDocument.cs#L825) a [private method in Utf8JsonWriter](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/b673eea8acacb1cdcfd5e59b7bbcab036eafa3ce/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Writer/Utf8JsonWriter.WriteValues.FormattedNumber.cs#L24) and writes the string directly into it.

With this discovery, I made what feels like a very hacky and inefficient implementation.

```cs
open System.Text.Json

void writeFloat(Utf8JsonWriter w, double d) {
  String floatStr = f.ToString("0.0################")
  JsonElement jse = JsonDocument.Parse(floatStr).RootElement
  jse.WriteTo(w)
}
```

I need to format a double anyway so that's fine, but parsing it, creating a jsonDocument and a JsonElement, just to be able to find a way to call a protected method, seems really wasteful. However, it does work (I wrote it in F# and translated to C#, apologies if I made an error in the syntax).

Is there a better way? Some potential solutions that come to mind (I'm new to dotnet so I'm not sure what's possible here):

- is there a way to access the [private API](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/b673eea8acacb1cdcfd5e59b7bbcab036eafa3ce/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Writer/Utf8JsonWriter.WriteValues.FormattedNumber.cs#L24) directly? I thought subclassing Utf8Writer might work but it's a sealed class.
- can I instantiate a JsonElement directly without the whole parsing rigmarole?

As for why this is necessary: I need to force integer values to be written with a `.0` appended because there is an extremely specific format that I need to interact with, which distinguishes between integer and floating-point JSON values.  (I'm OK with exponential format as that's clearly a float).

Comment: Have to tried writing a Custom Converter? However, it seems strange that the receiving party of this json is having so much trouble with the omitted decimal place

Comment: sounds like an x-y problem - why do you need that precision? if its that important why not transport it as a string?

Comment: The consumer of the data treats 82.0 and 82 as different values with different semantics, which cannot be changed at this time.

Comment: @00110001 How does a Custom Converter get around the problem?

Comment: A custom converter will give you fine grained control over the conversion of the type. Use can implement whole sales, or target the property via an attribute

Comment: @00110001 I've used custom converters before, so I'm familiar with them (though I had forgotten about them, so I appreciate the reminder!). However, there isn't a method available except a private one - does that get around that?

Comment: Also, aren't custom converters used for type-based serialization? That doesn't help in this case cause I'm not doing type-based (de)serialization.

Comment: Yeah, I may have misread the question. is there any reason why you aren't just serializing this using the regular methods ?

Comment: Yes, there is an extremely specific format that I need to interact with.

Comment: I am not sure you can do this out of the box. It seems every useful method you could use from the source code is internal. The only thing i can think of is to use reflection to dig into the Utf8JsonWriter. I would suggest taking this to github either way to get confirmation. The other thing you could do is use Json.net, which will give you access to `WriteRaw`

Comment: Some further information here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1784

Comment: Thanks @00110001, found that earlier and reported my issue: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1784#issuecomment-782919636

Comment: Hah i was wondering if that was you. Anyway good luck

Comment: Last note. if you really really wanted to, you could reflect this and achieve your desires. It wouldn't be too hard. Personally though, id consider json.net unless you needed something very specific

Comment: Does it work if you use `Decimal` instead? Since `Decimal` stores 82.0 and 82 differently.

Comment: Don't forget to dispose of the `JsonDocument`.

Comment: @mjwills Good idea with Decimal. I was avoiding it because it doesn't have the range of a float, but I could check if the fractional part of the float is 0 and then try a decimal.

Comment: @PaulBiggar - what exactly are you looking for in an answer, given that you already have a way to do this using `JsonDocument.Parse(floatStr)`?

Comment: Also, what do you want to do in cases where `System.Text.Json` would otherwise output in exponential format? e.g. `JsonSerializer.Serialize(7e27)` currently gives `7E+27`.

Comment: @dbc a way of doing this that doesn't involve the JsonDocument.Parse. tbh, from my recent research I'm not sure there is such a way though.

Comment: @dbc I'm OK with exponential format as that's clearly a float. I'm basing the type of the output on the type of the input which is why I need it to not "pretend" to be an int.

Comment: @PaulBiggar - I was playing around with doing it using `decimal`.  It works in some cases but causes odd problems for large values that would otherwise be represented as exponential values, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/ooLJmZ.

Comment: This is the best I could do: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1se1LU.  It avoids `JsonDocument` by formatting and re-parsing to `decimal` with the required number of digits -- checking to make sure that the intermediate string really is an integer and not in an exponential format.  Is this what you want?  It might not actually be faster than `JsonDocument`, you should probably check that...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your **requirements** are to create a [`JsonConverter<double>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1) satisfying the following:

- When formatting `double` values in fixed format, when the value is an integer a `.0` fractional portion must be appended.
- No change when formatting in exponential format.
- No change when formatting non-finite doubles such as `double.PositiveInfinity`.
- No requirement to support [`JsonNumberHandling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonnumberhandling?view=net-5.0) options `WriteAsString` or `AllowReadingFromString`.
- No intermediate parsing to `JsonDocument`.

In **.NET 6 and later** you may format your double manually and write it out with [`Utf8JsonWriter.WriteRawValue()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonwriter.writerawvalue?view=net-6.0).  The following converter functions as required:

```
public class DoubleConverter : JsonConverter<double>
{
    const bool skipInputValidation = true; // Set to true to prevent intermediate parsing.  Be careful to ensure your raw JSON is well-formed.

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, double value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        Span<byte> utf8bytes = stackalloc byte[33]; // JsonConstants.MaximumFormatDecimalLength + 2, https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v6.0.11/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/JsonConstants.cs#L85
        if (!double.IsFinite(value))
            // Utf8JsonWriter does not take into account JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling so we have to make a recursive call to serialize
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, new JsonSerializerOptions { NumberHandling = options.NumberHandling });
        else if (Utf8Formatter.TryFormat(value, utf8bytes.Slice(0, utf8bytes.Length-2), out var bytesWritten))
        {
            // Check to make sure the value was actually serialized as an integer and not, say, using scientific notation for large values.
            if (IsInteger(utf8bytes, bytesWritten))
            {
                utf8bytes[bytesWritten++] = (byte)'.';
                utf8bytes[bytesWritten++] = (byte)'0';
            }   
            writer.WriteRawValue(utf8bytes.Slice(0, bytesWritten), skipInputValidation);
        }
        else // Buffer was too small?
            writer.WriteNumberValue(value);
    }
    
    static bool IsInteger(Span<byte> utf8bytes, int bytesWritten)
    {
        if (bytesWritten <= 0)
            return false;
        var start = utf8bytes[0] == '-' ? 1 : 0;
        for (var i = start; i < bytesWritten; i++)
            if (!(utf8bytes[i] >= '0' && utf8bytes[i] <= '9'))
                return false;
        return start < bytesWritten;
    }
    
    public override double Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        // TODO: Handle "NaN", "Infinity", "-Infinity"
        reader.GetDouble();
}
```

Notes:

- For performance I format the value to a utf8 stackalloc'ed `byte` array using [`Utf8Formatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.text.utf8formatter?view=net-6.0), then add the `.0` if required, then finally write using `skipInputValidation = true`.  Doing so should result in best performance, as `Utf8JsonWriter` is designed to write directly to utf8 buffers or streams rather than to utf16 text writers whose contents are subsequently encoded to utf8.
- `Utf8Formatter` produces locale-invariant output, but if you use a `ToString()` method such as `f.ToString("0.0################")`, be sure to do so in the invariant locale like so:

  ```
  f.ToString("0.0################", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
  ```

  This guarantees that the correct JSON decimal separator `.` will be used even in locales where a comma is used.
- The `double.IsFinite(value)` check is intended to serialize non-finite values like `double.PositiveInfinity` correctly.  Upon experimentation I have found that `Utf8JsonWriter.WriteNumberValue(value)` throws unconditionally for these types of value so the serializer must be called to properly handle them when `JsonNumberHandling.AllowNamedFloatingPointLiterals` is enabled.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U9os9h).

In **.NET 5 and earlier** `Utf8JsonWriter.WriteRawValue()` do not exist, so, as suggested by [mjwills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills) in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66309150/how-do-i-write-a-float-like-82-0-with-the-0-intact-using-utf8jsonwriter#comment117229562_66309150), you can convert the `double` to a `decimal` with the required fractional component, then write that to JSON as follows:

```
public class DoubleConverter : JsonConverter<double>
{
    // 2^49 is the largest power of 2 with fewer than 15 decimal digits.  
    // From experimentation casting to decimal does not lose precision for these values.
    const double MaxPreciselyRepresentedIntValue = (1L<<49);

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, double value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        bool written = false;
        // For performance check to see that the incoming double is an integer
        if ((value % 1) == 0)
        {
            if (value < MaxPreciselyRepresentedIntValue && value > -MaxPreciselyRepresentedIntValue)
            {
                writer.WriteNumberValue(0.0m + (decimal)value);
                written = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // Directly casting these larger values from double to decimal seems to result in precision loss, as noted in  https://stackoverflow.com/q/7453900/3744182
                // And also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todecimal?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToDecimal_System_Double_
                // > The Decimal value returned by Convert.ToDecimal(Double) contains a maximum of 15 significant digits.
                // So if we want the full G17 precision we have to format and parse ourselves.
                //
                // Utf8Formatter and Utf8Parser should give the best performance for this, but, according to MSFT, 
                // on frameworks earlier than .NET Core 3.0 Utf8Formatter does not produce roundtrippable strings.  For details see
                // https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/eb03e0f7bc396736c7ac59cf8f135d7c632860dd/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Writer/Utf8JsonWriter.WriteValues.Double.cs#L103
                // You may want format to string and parse in earlier frameworks -- or just use JsonDocument on these earlier versions.
                Span<byte> utf8bytes = stackalloc byte[32];
                if (Utf8Formatter.TryFormat(value, utf8bytes.Slice(0, utf8bytes.Length-2), out var bytesWritten)
                    && IsInteger(utf8bytes, bytesWritten))
                {
                    utf8bytes[bytesWritten++] = (byte)'.';
                    utf8bytes[bytesWritten++] = (byte)'0';
                    if (Utf8Parser.TryParse(utf8bytes.Slice(0, bytesWritten), out decimal d, out var _))
                    {
                        writer.WriteNumberValue(d);
                        written = true;
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
        if (!written)
        {
            if (double.IsFinite(value))
                writer.WriteNumberValue(value);
            else
                // Utf8JsonWriter does not take into account JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling so we have to make a recursive call to serialize
                JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, new JsonSerializerOptions { NumberHandling = options.NumberHandling });
        }
    }
    
    static bool IsInteger(Span<byte> utf8bytes, int bytesWritten)
    {
        if (bytesWritten <= 0)
            return false;
        var start = utf8bytes[0] == '-' ? 1 : 0;
        for (var i = start; i < bytesWritten; i++)
            if (!(utf8bytes[i] >= '0' && utf8bytes[i] <= '9'))
                return false;
        return start < bytesWritten;
    }
    
    public override double Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        // TODO: Handle "NaN", "Infinity", "-Infinity"
        reader.GetDouble();
}
```

Notes:

- This works because `decimal` (unlike `double`) retains trailing zeros, as mentioned in the [documentation remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-5.0#remarks).
- Unconditionally casting a `double` to a `decimal` can [lose precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7453900/3744182) for large values, so simply doing

  ```
  writer.WriteNumberValue(0.0m + (decimal)value);
  ```

  to force a minimal number of digits is not recommended.  (E.g. serializing `9999999999999992` would result in `9999999999999990.0` rather than `9999999999999992.0`.)

  However, according to the Wikipedia page [Double-precision floating-point format: Precision limitations on integer values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#Precision_limitations_on_integer_values), integers from −2^53 to 2^53 can exactly represented as a `double`, so casting to decimal and forcing a minimal number of digits can be used for values in that range.
- Other than that, there is no way to directly set the number of digits of a .Net `decimal` in runtime beyond parsing it from some textual representation.  For performance I use [`Utf8Formatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.text.utf8formatter?view=net-5.0) and [`Utf8Parser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.text.utf8parser?view=net-5.0), however in frameworks earlier than .NET Core 3.0 this might lose precision, and regular `string` formatting and parsing should be used instead.  For details see [the code comments for `Utf8JsonWriter.WriteValues.Double.cs`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/eb03e0f7bc396736c7ac59cf8f135d7c632860dd/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Writer/Utf8JsonWriter.WriteValues.Double.cs#L103).
- You asked, *is there a way to access the private API directly?*

  You can always use reflection to call a private method as shown in *[How do I use reflection to invoke a private method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135443/3744182)*, however this is not recommended as internal methods can be changed at any time, thereby breaking your implementation.  Beyond that there is no public API to write "raw" JSON directly, other than parsing it to a `JsonDocument` then writing that.  I had to use the same trick in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65350863/3744182) to *[Serialising BigInteger using System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64788895/3744182)*.
- You asked, *can I instantiate a JsonElement directly without the whole parsing rigmarole?*

  This is not possible as of .NET 5.  As shown in its [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.3/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Document/JsonElement.cs), the `JsonElement` struct simply contains a reference to its parent `JsonDocument _parent` along with a location index indicating where the element is located within the document.

  In fact in .NET 5 when you deserialize to a `JsonElement` using `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement>(string)`, internally [`JsonElementConverter`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.3/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Converters/Value/JsonElementConverter.cs) reads the incoming JSON into a temporary `JsonDocument`, clones its `RootElement`, then disposes of the document and returns the clone.
- The special case for `value < MaxPreciselyRepresentedIntValue` is intended to maximize performance by avoiding any round-tripping to a textual representation when possible.

  I haven't actually profiled to confirm that this is faster than doing a textual round-trip however.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7pwvaT) which includes some unit tests asserting that the converter generates the same output as Json.NET for a wide range of integer `double` values, as Json.NET always appends a `.0` when serializing these.

Comment: Amazing answer!

Comment: What's happening in the `else` block of the `isFinite` condition?

Comment: @PaulBiggar - I added some additional test cases to my fiddle here https://dotnetfiddle.net/7pwvaT and found inconsistencies with Json.NET for integer values between 2^49 and 2^53, so I tweaked the value of `MaxPreciselyRepresentedIntValue`.